# React-Native | ScrollView right to left

Tags: uiscrollview, react-native, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I've got a simple ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView
    style={$style.category_container}
    horizontal={true}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={true}
>
    <Item title={'1'} />
    <Item title={'2'} />
</ScrollView>
```

Item is a component that loads several thumbnails. My application is planned for both LTR and RTL users, so there is a change in directions for RTL.

The problem is when I'm using the RTL interface - the `ScrollView` is still moving from left to right, and I can't see all my thumbnails.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Try this:
`<View style={{direction: 'rtl'}}><ScrollView ... /></View>`


Direction can be set as rtl, ltr, inherit, initial, revert or unset

Answer (score 16):

If someone will run into this in the future:
There isn't any 'built-in' property that will set ScrollView's direction to RTL at the moment.

However That's what worked for me:

- set `flexDirection: 'row-reverse'` to ScrollView's style, which will order your items from right to left.
- use `onContentSizeChange` to init list's scroll on the right side.

Here's an example:

```
scrollListToStart(contentWidth, contentHeight) {
    if (I18nManager.isRTL) {
        this.scrollView.scrollTo({x: contentWidth});
    }
}

render() {
    let containerStyle = I18nManager.isRTL ? styles.RTLContainer : styles.LTRContainer;

    return (
        <ScrollView
            ref={ref => this.scrollView = ref}
            onContentSizeChange={this.scrollListToStart.bind(this)}
            horizontal={true}
            style={[styles.buttonsContainer, containerStyle]}>
            {this.renderButtons()}
        </ScrollView>
    )
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    RTLContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row-reverse'
    },

    LTRContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row'
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I've already disabled the forceRTL option - and any RTL style work with local adjustment. I can agree that your solution is the right way to make things work because I did it myself few weeks ago. Hope it would help other people.

Answer (score 15):

you can use this way 
i did this and worked for me
This solution has 2 rounds

1-first make this style for your scrollView : `style={{scaleX:-1}}`

2-second make this style for each of your childs in scrollView  : `style={{scaleX:-1}}`

For Example

```
 <ScrollView
                            horizontal={true}
                            contentContainerStyle={{height: 65}}
                            style={{scaleX:-1}}
                            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
                            {
                                data.sports.map((data,index) => {
                                    return(
                                        <View key={index}
                                            style={{width:150,height:55,backgroundColor:'yellow', marginHorizontal:4,scaleX:-1}}/>
                                    )
                                })
                            }
                        </ScrollView>
```

As you can see my scrollview has `scaleX = -1` style
Also all of my childs in scrollView has `scaleX = -1` style

as scaleX is deprecated in views you can use `transform:[{rotateY:'180deg'}]` instead

Comment: It works like a charm!, just one thing, scaleX was deprecated, so you need to use `transform: [{ scaleX: -1}]` instead of `scaleX:-1`

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone has a similar problem to mine. I was doing a horizontal ScrollView with user images and needed the images to appear from right to left. Thank you Mr-Ash & Sergey Serduk for getting me there.

```
<ScrollView
  horizontal
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  style={{
    alignSelf: "center",
    borderRadius: 100,
    transform: [{ scaleX: -1 }],
  }}>
  {users.map((user, i) => {
    return (
      <View key={i} style={[{ transform: [{ scaleX: -1 }], zIndex: 100 - i }]}>
        <UserImage leftMargin={-27} />
      </View>
    );
  })}
  <View style={{ marginRight: 27 }} />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for modern react-native.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case a proper solution is wrapping a `<ScrollView/>` component with `<View/>` see below:

`<View style={{direction: 'rtl'}}><ScrollView ... /></View>`

Direction can be set as `rtl`, `ltr`, `inherit`, `initial`, `revert` or `unset`

Answer (score 0):

The best possible solution for RTL `ScrollView` is the combination of scrolling it to the end and `flex-direction: 'row-reverse'`

```
const scrollRef = useRef<any>();

const scrollToEnd = () => {
  scrollRef.current.scrollToEnd({ animated: false });
};
```

```
<ScrollView
   contentContainerStyle={{
     flexDirection: "row-reverse"
   }}
   onContentSizeChange={scrollToEnd}
   ref={scrollRefOne}
   horizontal
   showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
 >
...
</ScrollView>
```