# forcing a horizontal scrollview to start from the right hand side

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I have a SVG which is wider than the physical screen, therefore its sitting in a scrollview

`<ScrollView horizontal={true} contentOffset={{x:1315}} onScroll={this.handleScroll}>`

The onScroll function tells me that the maximum scroll width is 1320 when i scroll manually to the right

```
handleScroll= (event) => {
        console.log(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x)
       }
```

As you can see from the above I have my scroll view component set with the contentOffset param with x=1315 so it should be at least most of the way to the right but the scroll starts at its normal position on the far left

What have I done wrong?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

you can refer this link [React-Native | ScrollView right to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40507675/react-native-scrollview-right-to-left)

if you have no problem using a third party plugin you can try the following link

[react-native-invertible-scroll-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-invertible-scroll-view)